# How to remove \n from json object literal

Tags: javascript, json

When I write console.log(input), i get the below code but I don,t want to format it in this manner:

```
var contacts = { json: ' "book": {\n        
"person": [\n 
{\n
    "firstName": "Jane",\n 
    "lastName": "Doe",\n
    "age": "25",\n
    "address": {\n
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",\n
        "city": "Las Vegas",\n
        "state": "NV",\n
        "postalCode": "10021-3100"\n
    }\n
},\n
{\n
    "firstName": "Agatha",\n
    "lastName": "Doe",\n
    "age": "25",\n
    "address": {\n
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",\n
        "city": "Las Vegas",\n
        "state": "NV",\n
        "postalCode": "10021-3100"\n
        }\n
    }\n
  ]\n
}' }
```

How to convert above code in the below format?

```
var contacts = {
    "book": {
        "person": [
            {
                "firstName": "Jane",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "age": "25",
                "address": {
                    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                    "city": "Las Vegas",
                    "state": "NV",
                    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Agatha",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "age": "25",
                "address": {
                    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                    "city": "Las Vegas",
                    "state": "NV",
                    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Get rid of the `\n` and it'll validate as a JSON...where did you get that?

Comment: *"When I write `console.log(input)`, i get the below code but I don,t want to format it in this manner"* vs. `var contacts =`. Which is it? `input`, or `contacts`?

Comment: Why not pass the string through str.replace first? e.g. contacts.replace('\n','');

Comment: Try `contacts = JSON.parse(contacts.json)`

Answer (score 0):

> When I write `console.log(input)`, i get the below code but I don,t want to format it in this manner

*(I'm going to assume `input` is really `contacts`, the thing you quoted in your question.)*

The way the console formats its output depends almost entirely on the console. You can't control it directly. If you give it an object (which is what you're doing with `console.log(contacts)`), the implementation of the console will output that whatever way the people implementing it see fit, and it will vary from console to console — the output you see in Firefox's dev tools is different from Chrome's, and both of them are different from NodeJS's.

Most consoles will output strings in a fairly similar way (although their handling of quotes around the string varies), so you could turn your `input` into a string and output that. One way would be to use `JSON.stringify` on it:

```js
var contacts = {
    "book": {
        "person": [
            {
                "firstName": "Jane",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "age": "25",
                "address": {
                    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                    "city": "Las Vegas",
                    "state": "NV",
                    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Agatha",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "age": "25",
                "address": {
                    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                    "city": "Las Vegas",
                    "state": "NV",
                    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts));
```

Comment: See in User Interface- Text Area I am passing the JSON object but in entry point of my code "  this.execute = function(input,output){} ", when I write console.log(input) I get JSON object along with /n.

Comment: @PranjalSharma: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying with that comment. It sounds like you may have asked a question about the console when you really wanted to ask a different question. (People do that all the time.) If you really have a different question, spend some time ensuring you have a clear question and then post that (as a new question; this question has already been asked and answered).

Comment: Crowder could you please help me with the answer.

Comment: @PranjalSharma: Was there a part of "I don't understand what you're saying" that was unclear? :-)

Comment: Instead  of placing job inside the contacts object, just try the below code.


     var contact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(job));

Answer (score 0):

`json = ' "book": {
    "person": [
        {
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "age": "25",
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                "city": "Las Vegas",
                "state": "NV",
                "postalCode": "10021-3100"
            }
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Agatha",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "age": "25",
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                "city": "Las Vegas",
                "state": "NV",
                "postalCode": "10021-3100"
            }
        }
    ]
}'`

`var contact  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
    console.log(contact);`